# ifstream-istream and function call

Tags: c++, ifstream, istream

I am new to c++ and while i was working with streams i saw the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Results
{
    public:

        string const& operator[](int index) const
        {
            return m_data[index];
        }
        int size() const
        {
            return m_data.size();
        }
        void readnext(istream& str)
        {
            string line;
            getline(str, line);
            cout << "line :" << line <<endl;

            stringstream lineStream(line);
            string cell;

            m_data.clear();
            while(getline(lineStream, cell, ','))
            {
                m_data.push_back(cell);
                cout << cell<<endl;
            }

        }
    private:
        vector<string> m_data;
};



istream& operator>>(istream& str, Results & data)
{

    data.readnext(str);
    return str;
}   



int main()
{
    ifstream file("filename.txt");
    Results r1;
    while(file >> r1)
    {
        cout << "1st element: " << r1[3] << "\n";
    }
}
```

When the call `data.readnext(str)` is made:
1)what is the value of `str` which is passed as an argument? When I print it out and i get 0x7ffd30f01b10 which is an address.
2)in the function `getline(str, line);` gives line the value of the first row of the file. I don't get why. Shouldn't that be `getline(file, line);`
I generally don't understand how this works so any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Ask the person who wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

1. The value is a reference to the `std::istream` superclass of the instantiated `std::ifstream file` object.
2. No. There is no `file` object visible in the scope of the `readnext()` function. The code is correct. `str` is the `std::istream &` parameter to `readnext()`, and matches the type of the first parameter to `std::getline()`.

Comment: "subobject" might be better

Comment: so str is a reference to the std::ifstream file object?

Comment: If you take a look at what `str` is declared to be, as a parameter to the `readnext()` function, you should be able to answer your own question.